# C# Calculate field inside LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help to calculate a property inside my Linq query.

I know I need to use "let" somewhere, but I can't figure it out!

So, first I have this method to get my list from Database:

```
public BindingList<Builders> GetListBuilders()
    {
        BindingList<Builders> builderList = new BindingList<Builders>();
        var ctx = new IWMJEntities();
        var query = (from l in ctx.tblBuilders
                     select new Builders
                     {
                         ID = l.BuilderID,
                         Projeto = l.NomeProjeto,
                         Status = l.Status,
                         DataPedido = l.DataPedido,
                         DataPendente = l.DataPendente,
                         DataEntregue = l.DataEntregue,
                         DataAnulado = l.DataAnulado
                     });
        foreach (var list in query)
            builderList.Add(list);
        return builderList;
    }
```

Then, I have a function to calculate the Days between Dates accordingly to Status:

```
public int GetDays()
    {
        int Dias = 0;
        foreach (var record in GetListBuilders)
        {
            if (record.Status == "Recebido")
            {
                Dias = GetBusinessDays(record.DataPedido, DateTime.Now);
            }
            else if (record.Status == "Pendente")
            {
                Dias = GetBusinessDays(record.DataPedido, (DateTime)record.DataPendente);
            }
            else if (record.Status == "Entregue")
            {
                Dias = GetBusinessDays(record.DataPedido, (DateTime)record.DataEntregue);
            }
            else if (record.Status == "Anulado")
            {
                Dias = GetBusinessDays(record.DataPedido, (DateTime)record.DataAnulado);
            }
        }
        return Dias;
    }
```

I need to call the GetDays in a DataGridView to give the days for each record.

My big problem is, How do I get this? include it in Linq Query? Calling GetDays() (need to pass the ID from each record to GetDays() function)!?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is having your `GetBusinessDays` converted to SQL. Please show what's in there. It's not all that hard to use switch statements to dynamically change how you create your SQL string, but that usually requires using the fluent instead of SQL syntax. But, as you're doing it for just a single parameter, the SQL this generates would most likely be pretty bad. I would most likely recommend creating a View for this in the database and do a simple EF query against that.

Comment: The GetBusinessDays() it's a function that calculates the diference in Days between 2 Dates excluding weekends and holidays. This is not the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to create an extension method:

```
public static int GetBusinessDays(this Builders builder) // or type of ctx.tblBuilders if not the same
{
  if (builder == null) return 0;

  switch(builder.status)
  {
    case "Recebido": return GetBusinessDays(builder.DataPedido, DateTime.Now);
    case "Pendente": return GetBusinessDays(builder.DataPedido, (DateTime)builder.DataPendente);
    case "Entregue": return GetBusinessDays(builder.DataPedido, (DateTime)builder.DataEntregue);
    case "Anulado": GetBusinessDays(builder.DataPedido, (DateTime)builder.DataAnulado);
    default: return 0;
  }
}
```

Then, call it like that:

```
public BindingList<Builders> GetListBuilders()
    {
        BindingList<Builders> builderList = new BindingList<Builders>();
        var ctx = new IWMJEntities();
        var query = (from l in ctx.tblBuilders
                     select new Builders
                     {
                         ID = l.BuilderID,
                         Projeto = l.NomeProjeto,
                         Status = l.Status,
                         DataPedido = l.DataPedido,
                         DataPendente = l.DataPendente,
                         DataEntregue = l.DataEntregue,
                         DataAnulado = l.DataAnulado,
                         Dias = l.GetBusinessDays()
                     });
        foreach (var list in query)
            builderList.Add(list);
        return builderList;
    }
```

To do better, to convert a object to a new one, you should create a mapper.

Comment: Zysce, thanks, but calling GetBusinessDays() needs an argument... And I get Builders does not contain a definition for GetBusinessDays()

Comment: With a little tweaks on Zysce idea, I have accomplished what I need!

Answer (score -1):

Why does it need to be a part of the query? You can't execute C# code on the database. If you want the calculation to be done at the DB you could create a view.

You're query is executed as soon as the IQueryable is enumerated at the foreach loop. Why not just perform the calculation on each item as they are enumerated and set the property when you are adding each item to the list?